# How to get the percentage of error per each hotel with name for the following tables using CTE

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression

Table 1 errors:

```
hotel_id.    error
1.            x
2             y
3             z
1             a
2             b
```

table 2 hotel

```
hotel_id      name
1              marriott
2              Westin
3              Luxury
```

Result expected

```
hotel_name     percent_of_errors.  total_errors_for_the_hotel
marriott             40.                  2
westin               40                   2
luxury               20                   1
```

query

```
with failed as 
(select h.hotel_id as id,h.name as h_name,count(e.error) as count_per_h
from errors e
join hotel h
on h.hotel_id=e.hotel_id group by 1,2) ,

total as (select *  
from errors)

select t.hotel_id,
f.h_name,(f.count_per_h/count(t.error)) as percent
from total t
join failed f
on t.hotel_id=f.id
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, sql-server, postgres, …?

Answer (score 0):

you query would only yield one resukt as you have no `GROUP BY`

If you change your second cte so that it countts all erros, you can simply CROSS JOIN`  it to calcualte the percentage

```
with failed as 
(select h.hotel_id as id,h.name as h_name,count(e.error) as count_per_h
from errors e
join hotel h
on h.hotel_id=e.hotel_id group by 1,2) ,

total as (select COUNT(*) count_all_errors
from errors)

select f.id,
f.h_name,(f.count_per_h/t.count_all_errors) as percent
from 
 failed f CROSS JOIN total t
```

Comment: I see all 0 for percentages

Comment: i don't https://dbfiddle.uk/H3aGPw9Z

Answer (score 0):

To compute the contribution of each hotel to the overall error count, I would recommend window functions rather than multiple subqueries. We can then bring the hotel name with a join.

```
select h.hotel_name, e.pct
from hotel h
left join (
    select hotel_id, 
        100.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over() pct
    from errors 
    group by hotel_id
) e on e.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
```

Notes:

- the `left join` ensures that all hotels appear in the resultset, even those that have no errors at all (for which a `null` percent will show up)
- the multiplication by `100.0` forces decimal context in arithmetic operations, avoiding a potential problem with integer division (depending on your database, which you did not tag)